# How to eliminate one out of the three three-way switches

Tags: electrical

I have three switches that control the same for your light, I would like to keep two one of the top and bottom of the stairs and eliminate one in the middle. Is there a way to connect the wires in that switch box to eliminate the third switch

Comment: Cut the power, pull the switches from their boxes, **_do NOT disconnect any of the wiring_** and provide pictures of all the wiring. Someone will be able to tell you how to connect things up.

Comment: Yes this can be done but we need to know the wiring, normally you will have 2 3 way switches and 1 , 4 way. Depending on how it’s wired will dictate what is done to bypass the switch. If a 3 way connecting 2 of the wires together and capping the 3rd. A 4 way the travelers in and out are spliced together for A  then B so 2 splices the ground removed from the switch and a blank cover installed. Not much to it but we need to see how it is wired to provide specifics

Comment: Where exactly is the switch you want to remove? It might be required by code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, one of those three switches is a 4-way, or nothing would work.

The sequence is:  mains power --> 3-way --> 4-way --> 3-way --> light fixtures.

Whereas a 3-way flips which of two 'out' leads is connected to the single side, the 4-way flips the two incoming leads so that each is connected to one or the other of the two outgoing leads.

So, if your undesired switch is the 4-way, you merely need to tie the two incoming leads to the two outgoing leads.  If your undesired switch is the 3-way feeding the light fixtures, then tie the two incoming leads to the single outgoing lead.  Similarly, if you are removing the first 3-way, connect the incoming mains power to **ONE** of the leads.  Cap off the other lead there **and** at the box containing the 4way (you could replace the 4way with a 3-way but so far as I know that's not required by code).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should consider is that extra switches are typically not added for convenience and they are usually required by code.  I can't cite all of the rules where code requires switches, but its typically at each entrance to a room, and at the top and bottom of the stairs.

You didn't explain exactly how you have a switch in the middle of the stairs, but if there is a landing that leads to a room in the middle, that switch is required.

There is a chance that a remodel has actually rendered a switch totally useless and in some cases removal is an option, but most of the time someone "never uses that switch" and wants to remove it even though it has a legitimate use.